# Jolt nesting with cutting part of JSON

Tags: json, jolt

I have this kind of JSON:

```
 {
  "id": "d9cb6cfc-3d9b-4b42-b65c-385d927cc25d",
  "ts": 1585215553702000,
  "measurements": {
    "CurrentVoltageAnglePhaseC": {
      "value": 0.012110710144042969,
      "processed": true
    },
    "CurrentAngleSeqNegativeA": {
      "value": 1.8299387848210902,
      "processed": true
    },
    "A6": {
      "value": 6.003753662109375,
      "processed": true
    },
    "D2": {
      "value": 1,
      "processed": true
    }
  }
}
```

On the output I need to get this kind of JSON (cut one level):

```
 {
  "ts" : 1585215553702000,
  "id" : "d9cb6cfc-3d9b-4b42-b65c-385d927cc25d",
  "CurrentVoltageAnglePhaseC" : "0.012110710144042969",
  "CurrentAngleSeqNegativeA" : "1.8299387848210902",
  "A6" : "6.003753662109375",
  "D2" : "1"
}
```

Do I have this functionality on JOLT transformation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "ts": "ts",
      "measurements": {
        "CurrentVoltageAnglePhaseC": {
          "value": "CurrentVoltageAnglePhaseC"
        },
        "CurrentAngleSeqNegativeA": {
          "value": "CurrentAngleSeqNegativeA"
        },
        "A6": {
          "value": "A6"
        },
        "D2": {
          "value": "D2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```